# Latitude/Longitude Combinations within Bounding Box

Tags: c#, math, geospatial

Given a bounding box, I would like to be able to calculate all possible latitude/longitude combinations within that box, to a certain accuracy e.g. 3 decimal places.  At the moment the calculations are done is real time, which is very slow.  To help speed things up I plan to use something like AppFabric Caching to cache a dataset of all points/distance combinations.  If done correctly this should reduce the distance calculation to a lookup.

The only piece of the puzzle that I'm missing is an efficient way to calculate the combinations of lat/lon in the bounding box - can anyone help?

Mark

Comment: What sort of projection does the map have?

Comment: @markpirvine
 Why do you want all possible combinations? Isn't it enough just to know if a certain point is inside a bounding box? This would be way easier to compute.

Comment: I think Reinderien is assuming an aligned rectangular bounding box. But as well as what map projection are you using, what box shape/projection are you intending? Sort of two sides of the same coin...

Comment: How big is the "box"? Small enough (well under a degree) to be treated as locally flat or not?

Comment: @adi I would like all combinations so that I can be confident that all distance calculations can be done without an expensive web service lookup.  Removing some accuracy from the lat/lon points should have the same effect of creating many bounding boxes?

Comment: @keith the box will be well under a degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still a bit mystified as to why you want all such points rather than just checking a given point is in the box on the fly (this does *not* take much computation).

However, given a small box, we can treat is as locally flat.

That means we transform any point to new coordinates:

```
(llat, llong) -> (x = llong * cos(llat), y = llong)
```

[Note the cos() is not an expensive function - unless you are still on a 486!]

The problem then reduces to that for a cartesian plane.

Assuming that by "box" you mean a rectangle, not necessarily oriented.

The obvious thing to do is rasterize it.

- Find the extremal latitude points from your box.
- For each latitude within the range find the pair of longitudes which intersect the edges. [It's for this edge interesection that you use the local flatness and just consider straight line intersections.]
- All longitudes within the interval defined by that pair of longitudes are in the set you seek.
- Maybe all your actually store are the interval end points rather than all points.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that calculating "all of the latitude and longitude combinations" within a certain box shouldn't be sped up; it shouldn't be done at all. Instead, you should derive functions that run along the four edges of the bounding box. For instance, for varying `x` and constant `y_top`, derive functions `lat(x)` and `long(x)`. Given two functions for four edges = eight functions total, you should be able to develop fast logic that determines whether or not any given coordinate is in the bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

I would concur with the other answers that normally you wouldn't want to create a list of all latitude / longitude combinations.

If you're using SQL Server 2008 or 2012, using the STContains() or STIntersects() methods are pretty easy and with a spatial index, very fast.